# I would like to divide a metric in datadog by the selected time

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I'm using Datadog for monitoring and analytics, and I have a specific use-case where I'm collecting metrics on error duration. What I would like to do is calculate the error rate per selected time interval, essentially dividing the accumulated error duration by the time interval.

Conceptually, this would look like this:

`Error rate = (Accumulated Error Duration)/(Selected Time Interval)`

I understand that Datadog has functionalities for arithmetic operations among metrics, but I'm not sure how to apply this to get the desired error rate per time interval as the interval changes. Is it possible to perform this operation within Datadog?

If yes, can anyone provide guidance on how I can accomplish this? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you can provide example queries or scripts, that would be even more helpful.

If no, could you suggest any alternative methods or tools that I could use to calculate this rate outside of Datadog?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm able to statically dived the error duration. But i would like to find a dynamic way where the time interval follow the one chosen in Datadog